# unable to run uibmodal in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am trying to show a modal using $uibModal using typescript and angular.

```
    export class PDPController{

    static $inject = ['pdpService', '$sce', 'angularLoad', '$uibModalInstance'];
    constructor(
        pdpService: PDPService, 
        $sce : ng.ISCEService, 
        angularLoad,
        //initiating in constructor
        private $uibModalInstance:ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance
    ) {
        this.pdpService=pdpService;
        //Need to add promise
        pdpService.getContentdata(APP_CONSTANT.API_URL_LEARN_MORE)
            .then((authorContentData) => {
            this.contentData= authorContentData;
            pdpService.getPDPdata(APP_CONSTANT.API_URL_LEARN_MORE)
            .then((pdpData) => {
            console.log(pdpData);
            this.setProductDetails(pdpData);
        });
        });

    }
    //method to invoke the modal
    private showPromo(): void{

        console.log("Promo");
          var modalInstance = this.$uibModal.open({
              animation: "true",
              templateUrl: 'promoModalContent.html',
              appendTo: 'body'
            });
    }
}

//module:
let module: ng.IModule = angular.module(pdpModule, ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

i am facing this error when i run the Gulp Build:

```
Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance
Module 'angular.ui' has no exported member 'bootstrap'.
```

$uibModal is not recognized when i run the code:
Error: Property '$uibModal' does not exist on type 'PDPController'.

I am completely new to Typescript and unable to figure out the way out here.
Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve this issue...but dont really know how this worked!
edits i made:

```
export class PDPController {
    public $uibModal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService;
    public modal: any;

    //injected $uibModal
    static $inject = ['pdpService', '$sce', 'angularLoad', '$uibModal'];
    //initiated $uibModal
    constructor(
        pdpService: PDPService,
        $sce: ng.ISCEService,
        angularLoad,
        $uibModal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService
    ) {
        // i had to assign the value of $uibModal to a new variable, otherwise
        //$uibModal is undefined when accessed in the function showPromo().
        this.modal = $uibModal;
    }

    private showPromo(): void {

        let modalInstance = this.modal.open({
            animation: "true",
            templateUrl: 'promoModalContent.html'
        });
    }
}
```

It will be great if somebody can explain why we needed a new variable!

Comment: You missed the uibModal and was using uibModalInstance

Answer (score 0):

You didn't inject `$uibModal`. Try to add it in your `$inject`:

```
static $inject = ['pdpService', '$sce', 'angularLoad', '$uibModalInstance', '$uibModal'];
```

Comment: Tried that...not working!
Can you please tell how to resolve this particular error->

Module 'angular.ui' has no exported member 'bootstrap'.